# How to start/stop service on a remote computer with an out of sync clock

Tags: windows, services, remote-access, wmi, powershell-2.0

I'm working in a MS Windows Domain.

I'm trying to centrally (remotely) start and stop the W32Time service for a certain amount of time (to disable Time Server update e.g for two hours) then remotely change system date and time to allow users with low power (they can't start and stop the service and change time) to do some backdated operations.
When the amount of time then finish, I want to start back the W32Time again to allow the auto sync of the system clock.

I've tried this with WMI, but my problem is that when I try to start back the service the time skew is too big and I can't do WMI operations.

Is it possible to do this?

I'm wondering if a solution maybe to put a shell file (that maybe finally deletes itself) on the remote system and then launch it with Admin privileges (using somenthing like PsExec). In that case I don't need to be granted by the DC and the time skew may not be a problem.

Maybe this is a more viable way?

Comment: Finally I came up with modifying my requirements. I wrote and distributed a simple c# exe with the start/stop time service and a form to request new date/time. This exe is remotely launched with admin privileges. This solved with quite little effort.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the time names of the files?

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html

If you insist on the Gordian Knot method, then you'll need to run the commands under the local Admin account.  The reason your WMI operations fail is because the workstation is trying to get authentication from the DC and the DC rejects it due to its invalid security token.

Comment: The tool you suggest is a good tool only for a part of my problem. The backdated activity is quite more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup schedule tasks through Group Policy. If you put it in the "Computer Configuration" section, it will get system privileges which should allow it to do anything.

You may also allow users to trigger tasks themselves, but I am not sure if credentials are needed to trigger system tasks.